# C# AutoCAD Publish not including layer information

Tags: c#, autocad, autocad-plugin

I'm writing an AutoCAD tool that publishes drawings from a dsd file. Although the DSD file has the relevant line "IncludeLayer=True", the publish method isn't pushing layer information. I attempted to add it via unrecognized data, however I'm still not getting layer information. Any ideas?

```
dsdData.ReadDsd(project.DSDPath);
dsdData.SetUnrecognizedData("IncludeLayer", "True");

PlotConfig plotConfig = Autodesk.AutoCAD.PlottingServices.PlotConfigManager.SetCurrentConfig("DWG To PDF.pc3");
Autodesk.AutoCAD.Publishing.Publisher publisher = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.Publisher;
publisher.PublishExecute(dsdData, plotConfig);
```

Comment: Can you give a quick try with TRUE (upper case) instead True?

Comment: I'm thoroughly amused that this works. Can I somehow mark your comment as the answer? Thank you very much!

Comment: added as an answer :-) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use **true** with uppercase

```
dsdData.SetUnrecognizedData("IncludeLayer", "TRUE");
```